# Move image next to header?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get an image and a header to be centered on the page next to each other. I can get the text centered but the image only sticks to the left or the right.

```css
.header {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 35px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 14px -14px gray;
}

.headerlogo {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 70px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="./img/LOGO.png" alt="Logo" class="headerlogo">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your css to:

```css
.header {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 35px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="./img/LOGO.png" alt="Logo" class="headerlogo">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
```

This will align all the items in your header in the center.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `position: relative`, instead of use `display`